# two wifi networks on raspberry pi zero w

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

This is a very specific use case: I need the **RPi zero w** to generate a local Wifi network that my client will connect to from a smart phone,  browse to a specific IP address and setup the second wifi connection through a web form (ssid & psk).

The idea is that my final product has no screen, and it needs to be configured by the user to reach its wifi network.

For now, I'm able to create a local wifi network (I only tried on B+), and use the ethernet port to reach the internet, but I will not have ethernet on my final product.

My question is: is that possible? and if so, how?

I'm open to other ideas to reach the same goal (why not Bluetooth...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Look for the recipes wlan to eth with NAT, then replace `eth0` with your `wlan1`. One excellent is, albeit in German, this one which walks you through all the gory details: https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/raspberry-pi/2002171.htm

While I'm writing this on my desk is sitting a Zero W with it's internal `wlan0` acting as AP. Connected to it is a tablet. I've an USB WLAN dongle attached via an USB OTG shim, it connects to my home network with Internet access. I only need it to update the Pi. But it is possible to NAT between the upstream additional `wlan1` and the AP `wlan0`. Bridging is not possible, but routing is. I've done this all also on a Pi 3B beginning of this year. The NAT rules even work when the `wlan1` upstream IP is dynamic. I was working from the description I linked to above.